# heroku App not deploying error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, heroku

(it's a flask python app)
the error is:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ikp3db==1.4.5 (from versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.4.1)`
and in the requirement.txt file i rewrote it to be `ikp3db==1.4`  but still the error is still i used the following commands:

```
heroku login
heroku create
heroku git:remote app-name
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master(i also tried using main)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the latest version of `ikp3db` is [1.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/ikp3db/#history). There is no 1.4.5. Use `1.4.1` in your `requirement.txt`.